If $a<b\leq c < d$ then $a^2+d^2 \geq b^2 +c^2$
I'm trying to prove (or find a counter example) for the following:
Let $a,b,c,d \in [0,1]$ and satisfying $a<b\leq c <d$. If $a+d = c+b$ then $$a^2+d^2 \geq c^2+b^2$$
Attempt to prove: From $a+d = b+c$ we get $$a^2+d^2 = b^2+c^2 + 2(bc-ad)$$ If $bc\geq ad$ then we are done because $$a^2+d^2 = b^2 +c^2 +2(bc-ad) \geq b^2+c^2$$
But I don't really see how $bc \geq ad$ follows from $a<b\leq c <d$.
Counter-examples are welcome too :)

Here's how to ask a good question. Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Where did you use $a+d=c+b$ in your tryings?

Added some more information due to the downvoting :)

@Kzards It's the other way around, you got downvoted because your lack of work. Good to see that you fixed that.

You have a typo. It should be $a^2 + \color{red}{d}^2$

Thx @jjagmath, fixed the typo XD

To see that $bc \ge ad$ just replace $d$ by $b+c-a$ to get $bc\ge a(b+c-a)$ which is equivalent to $(b-a)(c-a)\ge0$ which is true by the hypothesis.
(Note that the inequality doesn't require the hypothesis of the numbers being in $[0,1]$)

Amazing! I few so uninteligent lol
